# A class of pairs $(f,g)$ of functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

Playing with the Fourier cosine and sine transforms, I am wondering if anything is known about the class (set) of pairs of functions $(f,g)$ such that

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(xt)dx\equiv \int_0^\infty g(x)\sin(xt)dx\tag{1}$$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're only integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ (instead of the usual $-\infty$ to $\infty$?)

Either way, 
$$
\hat f_c(t) = \int_{0}^\infty f(x) \cos(xt)\,dx
$$

is necessarily even as a function of $t$, and

$$
\hat g_s(t) = \int_{0}^\infty g(x) \sin(xt)\,dx
$$

is necessarily odd, so the two transforms must be $0$. If the limits were $-\infty,\infty$, then this would only imply $f$ is odd and $g$ is even, and not much more.

Comment: Are you saying that equation (1) implies that $f=g=0$. However, if the limits were instead $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ then equation (1) with the new limits would imply that whatever $f$ and $g$ are, $f$ must be odd and $g$ even ?

Comment: equation (1), with either set of limits, implies the *transforms* are both zero (this does **not** necessarily imply that $f$ and/or $g$ are zero). In the case the limits are $-\infty,\infty$, the cosine transform of a function is zero if and only if the function is odd, and vice-versa for the sine transform, so it would imply $f$ is odd and $g$ is even. In the case of the limits you have, you couldn't make such a conclusion (since the integral doesn't even include $x<0$, odd/even properties can't play a role)

Comment: @ BaronVT in your first sentence you say "...implies the transforms are both zero," but could they not both be non-zero constant ?

Comment: no, the only constant odd function is $0$